# Would a hole in a heart make it unsuitable for transplantation?

Tags: cardiology, transplantation, surgery

Would a hole in a heart instantly make it unsuitable for transplantation? Or could it be possible for a heart with a congenital defect to still be suitable for use is someone else's body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to a [patent foramen ovale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atrial_septal_defect#Patent_foramen_ovale).

A Google Scholar search for [donor heart "patent foramen ovale"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=donor+heart+"patent+foramen+ovale") returns many results about transplanted hearts with PFO, which suggests to me that this is not a contraindication for donation, though that may be up to the transplant team or hospital. In most cases, PFO is not symptomatic; it could also be potentially repaired at the time of transplant if it was deemed significant.